# Java - Multiple Generics in one class

Tags: java, generics

I have the following class

```
class ReadFunction<T> {

    private final Function<UserDBResource, T> function;

    public ReadFunction(final Function<UserDBResource, T> function) {
        this.function = function;
    }

 
    public <R extends DBResource> T readValue(final R resource,
       ) {
        return Util.supplyOrNull(() -> this.function.apply(resource);
    }
}
```

So I have a Class where generic T is the return type of "readValue". R is generic parameter type of readValue. How can I define R as a generic of the class, so that I can use R wherever I use UserDBResource( which extends DBResource)

Comment: `R` a generic of the class? Do you mean `class ReadFunction<T, R extends DBResource>`?

Comment: `class ReadFunction<T, R extends DBResource> {...}` and then use `R` in `readValue`, in the constructor and when defining `function`.

Answer (score 1):

Add `R` to the list of the class' generic parameter types.

```
class ReadFunction<R extends DBResource, T> {

    private final Function<R, T> function;

    public ReadFunction(final Function<R, T> function) {
         this.function = function;
    }

    public T readValue(final R resource) {
        return Util.supplyOrNull(() -> this.function.apply(resource));
    }

}
```

However, the given code does not actually implicate a necessity for `R extends DBResource`; you could just use `R` without any bounds, since you don't use any method defined in `DBResource`, although you might have to change the signature of `Util#supplyOrNull`, too.

Finally, you can loosen up the bounds even more to allow more functions to be passed to the constructor without altering any your other restrictions.

```
class ReadFunction<R extends DBResource, T> {

    private final Function<? super R, ? extends T> function;

    public ReadFunction(final Function<? super R, ? extends T> function) {
         this.function = function;
    }

    public T readValue(final R resource) {
        return Util.supplyOrNull(() -> this.function.apply(resource));
    }

}
```